# how do I select records that are missing a particular type of row

Tags: mysql

I have a payment table. Type 1 is new/first payment.  Type 11 is renew payment.  So each user should have one record of type 1.  But due to bad coding, right now, some records have only renew records.  I want to find all the records that are missing the type 1 record.  In the example below, it should return user 3.

```
user type amount
1    1    10
1    11   10
2    1    10
3    11   10
```

How should I write the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to find all users in the table that don't have a record of Type 1 is a `NOT EXISTS` using a subquery, as follows:

```
SELECT p.[user]
FROM payment p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM payment
    WHERE `user` = p.[user] 
      AND type   = 1)
```

Alternatively, this can be done with a `LEFT JOIN` and only selecting the non-matching rows:

```
SELECT p.[user]
FROM      payment p
LEFT JOIN payment p2 
       ON p2.[user] = p.[user] 
      AND p2.type = 1
WHERE p2.[user] IS NULL
```

Comment: that will not work in mysql mysql uses backticks to mark columns

Comment: Ah thanks, I missed the mysql tag - I'll update.